# What if... you had a bowl of electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism

My chemistry teacher used to tell us that if you had a soup bowl with only electrons in it, the explosion could make you fly to Pluto. Was he right? Could this happen?

Comment: A very similar question is discussed in what-if https://what-if.xkcd.com/140/. Let's say that if the whole moon were to be turned into electrons, the consequences would be slightly more severe.

Comment: @csiz I thought I had read a scenario like this but I couldn't remember where! Thanks for putting the link up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer would depend how densely the electrons are packed. Let's say we have 1 kg of electrons, meaning we would have about $N = 10^{30}$ of them. For simplicity, let's approximate by arranging all of these electrons arranged in a spherical shell of radius $r=0.1$ meters. By symmetry, the voltage at the location of each charge would be constant and would have the following value.

$$V = -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{Ne}{r}$$

We can thus compute the potential energy $U = \frac{1}{2}Q V$ associated with this configuration.

$$U = \frac{1}{2} \cdot Ne \cdot \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{Ne}{r} = \frac{N^2 e^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \approx \boxed{1.15 \times 10^{33} \text{ Joules}}$$

Ignoring air friction, the Earth's escape velocity is $v =11200$ meters / second, which for a $m=2\times 10^6$ kg space shuttle, would only require $E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 = 1.25 \times 10^{14}$ Joules.

So, yeah, you'd have way more than plenty sufficient energy.

Comment: good job, Trevor. simple and direct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you'd need less than $1\mu$g of electrons to get to Pluto :)

Comment: But will all of that energy be transferred to the object? Also in a spherical shell not all charges are a distance $r$ from all other charges right?

Comment: Rigth Aron, but I found this consideration inappropriate for the question. Also, it will suffice anyway

Comment: @AaronStevens No, but if you integrate over all of the charge it is as if they were. A charged spherical shell acts as if it were all concentrated at the center as far as electric fields outside of the shell are concerned.

Comment: Yep :) Also, even if we got .01% of that energy it is a lot :)

Comment: I'm not sure there would be anything left you could call "you" that would be making it to Pluto

Comment: It's important to note that even 1kg of electrons is a lot, a 150kg human has less than about 50 grams of electrons total.

Comment: Nacht is correct. It's like asking: If I set off a nuclear explosion will I travel first class to Pluto, with a decent movie and headrest? - Answer: 99.9999% No. --- Space is mostly empty so you're not likely to hit Pluto, you'd be incinerated so you're not likely to leave orbit, the bits and pieces would be highly charged, etc.

Comment: @AaronStevens a lot is a fair bit of an understatement. 0.01% of that would equal a trillion of the most powerful nuclear bomb ever made. I'm not sure there would much of earth left.

Comment: @csiz true :) I guess any sort of "instantaneous" acceleration that could throw you off the earth would be too large to even keep anything intact.

Comment: @CuriousStudent This means we need roughly the electrons of 100g of hydrogen in the bowl?

Answer (score 8):

A uniform sphere of radius $r$ and total charge $Q$ has an electric potential energy of $3Q^2/20\pi \epsilon_0 r$.

Let's say your bowl is like a sphere of radius 5 cm. If it's all water ( molecular weight 18$m_u$) and $\mu= 9/5$ of a mass unit for every electron, then the number of electrons is
$ N_e = 1000 \frac{4\pi r^3}{3}/\mu m_u = 5\times 10^{26}$

If all the nuclei were removed, the electric potential energy would be $7\times 10^{26}$ Joules.

Pluto is at about 40 au from the Sun, effectively to get there, you have to escape from Earth and escape from the Sun. To do this you would need to launch from the Earth with a carefully directed speed of at least 16 km/s. If your mass is 100 kg, that takes a mere $1.3\times 10^{10}$ J.